# How does lansoprazole degrade in acidic conditions (mechanism)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, organosulfur-compounds

[image]

Can anybody help me and explain the mechanism of reaction here? And also I was wondering when disulfide bond is made, can molecule dissociate, return to the previous state and make a disulfide bond when it gets to acidic environment again?

Comment: Exactly which part of the mechanism are you finding difficult? Most of it is relatively straightforward chemistry. In the first step you protonate the pyridine-type nitrogen in the benzimidazole ring, then do a nucleophilic attack with the pyridine. The third step is "just" a nucleophilic substitution on sulfur, etc. It's basically the same few reactions that you learn when starting out organic chemistry except that it's a bigger molecule with some heteroatoms instead of carbons.

Comment: @orthocresol I think OP might be confused in the first step; in the diagram, protonation of the N is skipped.  That's what makes the aromatic lose resonance states, and that's what makes the C a good electrophile for any configuration that restorores that dual ring resonance.

Comment: @orthocresol it retains aromaticity, but there are fewer resonance states if you can't move that double bond around the ring without knocking off that H+

Comment: @orthocresol (an aside not regarding OP) can we have resonance states with such different dipoles and asymmetries, or is that in fact a different species?  And in that picture, the C is a bullseye for a nucleophile with or without an added proton.  Together, this has made the first step confusing for *me*, and I agree that it's important to know which step *OP* is referring to.

Comment: @orthocresol so we can substitute this resonating thing at that C and expect a randomized chirality if we extract it?  The C(-NH=ring)(-NH+-ring)(-NC7H5OF3-CH2-)(-SO) looks like a floppy chiral center if the product of reaction 1 resonates like that, if the (-NH=ring) and (-NH+-ring) are not required to be symmetrical.

Comment: @sqykly (1) The product of reaction 1 isn't chiral anyway? I'm sorry but I'm really quite lost as to what you're describing. Need some diagrams or something. (2) If you have further questions please ask a new question. I don't want to continue replying here (comment section of someone else's question is not the place to do so). I've also cleared my comments

Comment: @orthocresol Sulfoxides can be chiral — but I don’t think that was what OP was asking ;)

Comment: @orthocresol fair enough